# Remote Xml file parsing using JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html-parsing

can i parse remote(not local) file using JS/Jquery?

i want to display remote xml file in html page without using server side scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a [standard browser security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) context.

If you don't mind using third party hosted server side scripting, then look into [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Comment: can you please suggest any method to parse remote xml file using HTML/JS/JQ

Comment: Not beyond the suggestion that I've already provided in my answer.